# Resolving problems in git am

Tags: patch, git-am

I've got a couple of problems with git am. I had a patch made from git format-patch and it usually worked nicely.

Now I just merged a couple of things and git am failed with:

`Applying: Improve speed of computes
error: patch failed: product_cost_incl_bom/models/product_product.py:38
error: product_cost_incl_bom/models/product_product.py: patch does not apply`

Then how do I know why the patch doesn't apply...Now the weird thing is this:

I then did this:

```
$: patch -p1 .git/rebase-apply/patch
patching file product_cost_incl_bom/__openerp__.py
patching file product_cost_incl_bom/models/mrp_bom.py
patching file product_cost_incl_bom/models/product_product.py
Hunk #2 succeeded at 39 with fuzz 1
```

So why does `git am` fails but `patch` doesn't. And what's the fuzz 1?